# Каким образом можно узнать размерность запакованной записи

Tags: java, delphi, jna

Имеется следующая структура, написанная на делфи, каким образом я могу узнать её размерность не используя непосредственно сам делфи? Размерность нужна для передачи данных через JNA

Может есть какие-то онлайн компиляторы для проверки размерности?

```
type
  TTransactionInfo = packed record
    Size      : Word;    // Size of TTransactionInfo - заполнить перед вызовом
    Kind      : Word;    // 0-оплата 1-скидка 2-бонус 3-потраты гостя
    Summa     : Comp;    // сумма в копейках
    RestCode  : Word;    // код ресторана
    LogDate   : Integer; // дата чека (0 -> 30/12/1899)
    UnitNum   : Byte;    // номер кассы
    CheckNo   : Integer; // номер чека
    Comment   : Array[0..255] of Char; //комментарий - для ручных транзакций
  end;
```

Comment: В данном случае только размер Char зависит от компилятора, остальное стабильно 2+2+8+2+4+1+4+256*(1 или 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл [компилятор](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_pascal_compiler), получил размерность через sizeOf(), ниже приведу пример кода.

UPD > 
Добавление директивы {$MODE DELPHI} исправляет ситуацию с Integer. А ещё есть директива {$MODE DELPHIUNICODE} - это если код из Delphi2009 и новее, где Char уже 2 байта, а не 1. Спасибо [zed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177722/zed) за добавление информации к ответу!

```
program getSize;

type
  TTransactionInfo = packed record
    Size      : Word;    // Size of TTransactionInfo - заполнить перед вызовом
    Kind      : Word;    // 0-оплата 1-скидка 2-бонус 3-потраты гостя
    Summa     : Comp;    // сумма в копейках
    RestCode  : Word;    // код ресторана
    LogDate   : Integer; // дата чека (0 -> 30/12/1899)
    UnitNum   : Byte;    // номер кассы
    CheckNo   : Integer; // номер чека
    Comment   : Array[0..255] of Char; //комментарий - для ручных транзакций
  end;

begin
  writeln(sizeOf(TTransactionInfo));
end.
```

Comment: Онлайн компилятор выдаёт только один из двух возможных размеров, не факт что правильный.

Comment: Судя по подсчёту - размерность выдало 279. Если посчитать как посоветовал [MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/291659/mbo), выходит также. Так что в целом было верно.

Comment: Там в онлайн-компиляторе FreePascal, а не Delphi, поэтому могут быть сюрпризы: https://i.imgur.com/nw8pX6J.png (размер структуры оказался равен 275 байтам, а размер Integer-а = 2 байта). Добавление директивы `{$MODE DELPHI}` исправило ситуацию с Integer. А ещё есть директива `{$MODE DELPHIUNICODE}` - это если код из Delphi2009 и новее, где Char уже 2 байта, а не 1.